# Change row color based on collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my orders `DataGrid`, I need to change the background color of the rows that the customer inside them exists multiple times in the collection.
[image]

In the `DataGrid` above I want Jimmy's orders colored in yellow since Jimmy has more than one order.
This is how I populate the `DataGrid`:

```
 var people = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person{CustName = "Jimmy", CustNum = 1, OrderNumber = "1111", OrederDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Helpers.GetRandom(1,10))},
            new Person{CustName = "Alex", CustNum = 5, OrderNumber = "2222", OrederDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Helpers.GetRandom(1,10))},
            new Person{CustName = "Jimmy", CustNum = 1, OrderNumber = "3333", OrederDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Helpers.GetRandom(1,10))},
            new Person{CustName = "Robert", CustNum = 7, OrderNumber = "4444", OrederDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Helpers.GetRandom(1,10))}
        };

        dgOrders.ItemsSource = people;
```

And the `XAML`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgOrders" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                      CanUserReorderColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="250">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer Number" Binding="{Binding CustNum}" Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer Name" Binding="{Binding CustName}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Number" Binding="{Binding OrderNumber}" Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding OrederDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" Width="Auto"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in conjunction with `DataGridRowStyle`. In converter pass `ItemsSource` of DataGrid and `CustName` property of current row.

Converter will check if more than 1 items exist in ItemSource with same CustName, return brush you want say `Brushes.Green` otherwise it will return `Brushes.Transparent`:

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Resources>
       <local:ItemCountToBrushConverter x:Key="ItemCountToBrushConverter"/>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
          <Setter Property="Background">
             <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemCountToBrushConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="ItemsSource"
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                       AncestorType=DataGrid}"/>
                     <Binding Path="CustName"/>
                </MultiBinding>
             </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
       </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    ....
</DataGrid>
```

Converter code:

```
public class ItemCountToBrushConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length == 2)
        {
            IEnumerable<Person> collection = (IEnumerable<Person>)values[0];
            int count = collection.Count(item => item.CustName ==
                                                  values[1].ToString());
            return (count > 1) ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Transparent;
        }
        return Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or add another property to your Person class (named Mark here). Set Mark to true in your view model when you want the view to highlight that person. The XAML looks like that:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgOrders" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="250">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer Number" Binding="{Binding CustNum}" Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer Name" Binding="{Binding CustName}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Number" Binding="{Binding OrderNumber}" Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding OrederDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" Width="Auto"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Mark}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```